# Edit/Delete HTML table w/Javascript or Jquery through modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, edit

Working on a project for early project and here's the objective:
Make a table where you can add/edit/delete movies. I've been able to add the movies to my table, but can't seem to figure out my edit and delete buttons. Any tips will help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title></title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>



 <h1>Movies List</h1>
      <div class="container-fluid">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalContainer">
       Add Movie
     </button>
     <div id="modalContainer" class="modal fade">
       <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" >&times;</button>
             <h4 class="modal-title">Enter a New Movie w/Director.</h4>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body">
             <div>
               <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="firstName" class="sr-only">Movie Name:</label>
                 <input id="firstName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Movie Name" />
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="lastName" class="sr-only">Director:</label>
                 <input id="lastName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Director" />
               </div>
               <button onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
             </div>
            </div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>



<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
        <table id="myTable" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Movie</th>
                <th>Director</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>The Terminator</td>
                <td>Jack Black</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>The Virgin Suicides</td>
                <td>Uve Bol</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">EDIT</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p><input type="text" class="input-sm" id="txtfname"/></p>
        <p><input type="text" class="input-sm" id="txtlname"/></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id= "btnEdit" onClick = "myEdit()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button id= "btnDelete" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->


    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    $('table tbody tr  td').on('click',function myEdit(){
      $("#myModal").modal("show");
      $("#txtfname").val($(this).closest('tr').children()[0].textContent);
      $("#txtlname").val($(this).closest('tr').children()[1].textContent);
      $("#tldr").val($(this).closest('tr').children()[0].textContent);
      $("#tldrs").val($(this).closest('tr').children()[1].textContent);
    });

    var toDos = []

        function myFunction() {
            var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
            var row = table.insertRow(1);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var len = table.rows.length;
            row.id = 'row_' + len;
            cell1.id = 'tldr';
            cell2.id = 'tldrs';

        cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
        cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById('lastName').value;

      var data = {firstName: document.getElementById('firstName').value,
      lastName: document.getElementById('lastName').value,
        };

      $('table tbody tr  td').on('click',function(){
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
        $("#txtfname").val($(this).closest('tr').children()[0].textContent);
        $("#txtlname").val($(this).closest('tr').children()[1].textContent);
        $("#tldr").val($(this).closest('tr').children()[0].textContent);
        $("#tldrs").val($(this).closest('tr').children()[1].textContent);
        });

    toDos.push(data);
    console.log(toDos);
  };

function myEdit(){

  $('table tbody tr  td').on('click',function myEdit(){
    $("#txtfname").val($(this).closest('tr').children()[0].textContent);
    $("#txtlname").val($(this).closest('tr').children()[1].textContent);
});
};

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's a fiddle as well but I had issues getting the jquery to function correctly.

https://jsfiddle.net/yabhjmz0/10/

Comment: have you check DataTable ? here is the link to it https://editor.datatables.net/examples/simple/inTableControls.html this is specifically built to do wonders with HTML tables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the modal by using there modal ID

```
 <button type="button" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" >
```

check this [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tojopaul/yabhjmz0/12/)

Comment: Nah it already calls the modal upon table row click, just not in the fiddle due to the jquery not working properly there. Upon table row click the modal pops to edit the text, but i can't figure out how to save the text to the row selected.